# Крашится приложение при смене клавиатуры

Tags: java, android

Имею приложение с фрагментами (вкладки). При нажатии на кнопку получаю данные из фрагментов.

Вроде бы все работает, но если выполнить действия, описанные ниже, приложение крашится.

- Открыть уведомление  `Выберите способ ввода` в статус баре (вылезет диалоговое окно)
- Выключить/включить физическую клавиатуру (диалог закроется)
- Нажать на кнопку в моем приложении.

По тостам видно, что во фрагментах заново вызываются методы `onCreate()`
`NPE` вылетает при попытке получить текст из `EditText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в манифест:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|smallestScreenSize"
```